# Updating Azure Data Studio

Tags: updates, tar, azure

I am using the Azure Data Studio Client App for managing Databases. Ubuntu 20.04. When I check for updates inside the AZ Data Studio i get a tar.gz in my downloads folder. No instructions as to what to do with the tar.gz. Does anyone know what I am supposed to do with this tar.gz?

Google seemed to have no answers i am a newbie at Linux. Sorry if this is obvious to to many. Thanks for your help! :)

Mark

Comment: I just wrote in their feedback form that Linux users are second class in Azure Data Studio and that their update process is nonsense =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can go to [Download and install Azure Data Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. Download the `.deb` file
3. Install it by running the following:

   ```
   cd ~
   sudo dpkg -i ./Downloads/azuredatastudio-linux-1.32.0.deb
   ```

   (At this time (10/10/2021) Version 1.32.0 is the latest, so replace that with whatever version you are installing)
4. Run Azure Data Studio

   ```
   azuredatastudio
   ```

It should be able to update your current version.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1175506)

Comment: Note, it only works with the command line. If you try to do this using the GUI for .deb you get an error about azure conflicting with azure. But from the command line it works and your connections are preserved (but any open tabs are closed).

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the official documentation from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15), you need to perform the following steps:

```
cd ~
cp ~/Downloads/azuredatastudio-linux-<version string>.tar.gz ~ 
tar -xvf ~/azuredatastudio-linux-<version string>.tar.gz 
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:~/azuredatastudio-linux-x64"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

In plain English, this means:

1. Copy the `.tar.gz` file to your Home directory
2. Expand the file
3. Add the application path to your `PATH`
4. Reload the Bash profile

As you already have Azure Data Studio installed, you can probably ditch steps 3 and 4, but do confirm that there is already something named `azuredatastudio-linux-x64` in your Home directory. If there isn’t, you may have the Snap version of the application installed, which updates itself as new releases are made available.

Comment: thanks matigo.  what do you mean by Home directory? cd $HOME ?

Comment: Your Home directory would look something like `/home/Mark` (depending on your username) 

Comment: i did all of the above and have confirmed that my folder has correct version of azure datastudio... azuredatastudio-linux-x64/bin$ ./azuredatastudio launches my new version. Unfortunately now I still have Application launcher  that launches old version. This is turning into a maintenance job... I will go fuss with the App launcher now. Thanks for your help,